# CancellationToken vs CancellationChangeToken

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cancellation-token

What are the differences between `CancellationToken` and `CancellationChangeToken`? When do I use which one?

It seems that they can be used for the same purpose. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Short answer:

`CancellationChangeToken` is a thin wrapper around `CancellationToken`, which exposes the token's cancellation state through the `HasChanged` property.

Since `CancellationChangeToken` implements the `IChangeToken` interface, it can be passed to any object that reacts to token changes, for example an `IMemoryCache`: Each cache entry can be set to expire under a specific set of conditions, which are abstracted by `IChangeToken` instances. These conditions may be, for example, configuration changes, or explicit invalidation requests by the user.

The `CancellationChangeToken` wrapper can be passed to one or more cache entries, in order to evict them upon cancellation. The devs could also have decided to directly take a `CancellationToken`; this would however have complicated the internal logic and the external API, compared to the abstraction through `IChangeToken`, which is very clean, extensible and working just as well.

---

### Long answer:

#### Interface `IChangeToken`

[`IChangeToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.ichangetoken?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) defines a means to track some kind of *token*, check whether it has *changed* (`HasChanged`), and possibly automatically trigger some *callbacks* once it has *changed*.

There are various implementations for `IChangeToken`; for example, they track files or configuration options.

#### What `CancellationChangeToken` does

A [look at the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/222043719d772ca9abea2131dce6412ef1b2a159/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/src/CancellationChangeToken.cs#L28) quickly shows that the `CancellationChangeToken` is a thin `IChangeToken` wrapper around `CancellationToken`:

```cs
public bool HasChanged => Token.IsCancellationRequested;
```

So its "changed" state directly corresponds to the underlying token's cancellation state.

On first sight, this seems quite odd: A `CancellationToken` already [offers support for registering automatic callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_CancellationToken_Register_System_Action_), so why introduce a wrapper that exposes much less functionality?

Well, there is actually at least one use case where an abstracted way of observing token states is needed:

#### Caching

ASP.NET Core offers different means of caching; I will use [`IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-imemorycache) as an example here, which offers a simple built-in memory-based key/value cache, and is usable with minimal effort.

To reduce performance impact for each request, it makes sense to cache frequently needed, expensive computations. However, one needs a way to keep track of active cache entries in order to evict them as soon as they become outdated. The problem is, that the cache entries can have very different conditions for becoming outdated, e.g. they depend on configuration values or local files (and need to be updated as soon as these configuration values or local files change), or have a regular time out.

The `IChangeToken` interface offers a simple way to abstract these eviction conditions away, such that the cache only has to check the state of the given `IChangeToken` object, instead of directly watching files, timers, and so on. The cache might even register a callback, such that a change of the token state directly triggers the eviction logic, so no polling is needed.

#### Back to our `CancellationChangeToken`

A `CancellationToken` allows to set a delay until it is automatically cancelled, so after wrapping it with a `CancellationChangeToken`, we can pass it to a cache entry for automated eviction:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if(!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("entry1", out DateTime cachedValue))
    {
        cachedValue = DateTime.Now;

        var cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .AddExpirationToken(new CancellationChangeToken(new CancellationTokenSource(5000).Token));

        _memoryCache.Set("entry1", cachedValue, cacheOptions);
    }

    return View("Index", cachedValue);
}
```

In this example, we cache the current timestamp. After 5 seconds, the cancellation token is cancelled, and the timestamp gets evicted.

However, this is does not yet justify the use of a `CancellationToken`, since the `IMemoryCache` already offers a way to set an expiration time through [`MemoryCacheEntryOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheentryoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Now we get to the real strengths of the token-based eviction: We can

- combine multiple `IChangeToken` instances into one [`CompositeChangeToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.compositechangetoken?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), and thus evict a cache entry once any of these instances change.
- use the same token for multiple cache entries, thus evicting them all at once.

The latter case is particularly interesting for us: Some cache entries might depend on each other, so when one becomes invalid, we might want to evict all of them. This can be achieved by assigning a shared `CancellationToken` to their *values*, and a corresponding `CancellationChangeToken` to the *entries* themselves. Once one of the cached *values* notices that it has become outdated (e.g. by being polled by some other part of the application), it cancels the token. The cancellation propagates to all cache entries that track the corresponding change token, and thus invalidates them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

`CancellationToken` is designed as a ***readonly struct*** (I assume that is due to performance reasons) so it cannot be extended (inherited). So if you want to use an abstraction for cancellation tokens, you cannot use `CancellationToken` ***struct***. For this you have to use `IChangeToken`.

So here arrive the ***class*** `CancellationChangeToken`. It is a ***class*** (not an ***struct*** as `CancellationToken`) and it implements `IChangeToken` ***interface***; and it wraps a `CancellationToken` ***struct*** (the real cancellation token)

So, if we want to use an abstraction of cancellation tokens, we have to use `IChangeToken` and its implementations ej: `CancellationChangeToken`.

When to use `CancellationToken` or `CancellationChangeToken`?

If we just care about changes notification we can use `CancellationToken`.
But, if we want to use cancellation tokens as an abstraction, we have to use `IChangeToken` and its implementations (`CancellationChangeToken`, etc)

Comment: This answer does not explain _why_ one would want to use an abstraction for `CancellationToken`: This would imply that there are other implementations for cancellation tokens in .NET, which is not true. Even if there were other implementations, `IChangeToken` would not be a good abstraction, since it exposes only extremely limited functionality and different semantics (e.g. `IsCancellationRequested` vs `HasChanged`). Actually, it is the other way round: We _have_ something that takes `IChangeToken` for responding to arbitrary changes, and want to pass our `CancellationToken` to it.

Comment: Also, `readonly struct` indeed **can implement interfaces** ([example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N0kXcu)). So, one could just implement `IChangeToken` directly in `CancellationToken`, instead of creating a very restricted wrapper class. The .NET devs did not do this, since `IChangeToken` resides in the packet `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives`, which is optional for most apps (excluding ASP.NET Core, where it is required).

Comment: The answer doesn't try to explain why one would want to use abstraction for CancellationToken, cause isn't the question.
Question:Differences and When use CancellationToken/CancellationChangeToken.
Also Right:CancellationToken can't be inherited(cause readonly struct).
My point:the main difference and reason to use one/another is due to desing.If CancellationToken was a class and it would implements IChangeToken, maybe CancellationChangeToken wouldn't exist(why would it exist? it's just a wrapper).But that's not the real design, thats why we have to use a wrapper as CancellationChangeToken.